# Is there some way to find the very cheapest hostel in a whole country?

Tags: budget, tips-and-tricks, hostels, accommodation-search-engines

I just had the urge to look up the cheapest hostel in all of Japan.

I tried each of HostelWorld, HostelBookers, and Hostels.com but each one had a mandatory requirement that I specify a city before giving me results.

I suppose I could find a list of all cities etc in Japan and search each in one of those sites and keep track of which hostel was cheapest in each, then finally sort that resulting list to find the cheapest of all. But where would I find a "complete" list cities with hostels, let alone hostels not in cities?

Is there some other accommodation search engine that doesn't require the city? Or some completely different method I haven't thought of?

---

I know prices fluctuate by season and such, that there are work-for-accommodation, that definitions of what's a hostel vs a guesthouse etc can vary. That's all fine, I'm talking about whatever similar criterion works for sites such as the ones I mentioned for one dorm bed, comparing prices for whatever date I search for.

Comment: About five years ago I stayed for five weeks in a hostel in Naha, Okinawa for 1000 yen per night. It's still listed on some sites but Google Maps insists it's permanently closed. Emails receive no reply.

Comment: Here's the full list of cities with hostels in Japan: https://www.hostelworld.com/hostels/Japan

Comment: @JonathanReez: It seems to only list five, but state that there are 95.... Oh now I see at the very bottom! (-:

Comment: Not only do prices fluctuate by season, they can vary depending on what day you ask the question. You also would have to be clear about what a hotel is. Does a guy who lets you sleep on his couch for $10 count?

Comment: @DJClayworth: I'm happy with any site/method that does its best to find the cheapest in a country, even if it's not guaranteed to be 100% accurate 100% of the time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Booking dot com you can find in the whole country and filter by "hostel" so you can get at once all the prices. Specifically for Japan [here's the link](https://www.booking.com/searchresults.ca.html?aid=304142&label=gen173nr-1DCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaGeIAQGYAQS4ARfIAQzYAQPoAQGIAgGoAgM&sid=fbf84dd7019407239380044665f6406a&tmpl=searchresults&ac_click_type=b&ac_position=0&checkin_month=2&checkin_monthday=4&checkin_year=2019&checkout_month=2&checkout_monthday=5&checkout_year=2019&class_interval=1&dest_id=106&dest_type=country&from_sf=1&group_adults=1&group_children=0&label_click=undef&nflt=concise_unit_type%3D1%3B&no_rooms=1&raw_dest_type=country&room1=A&sb_price_type=total&search_selected=1&shw_aparth=1&slp_r_match=0&ss=Jap%C3%B3&ss_raw=japan&ssb=empty&ssne=Debrecen&ssne_untouched=Debrecen&order=price) sorted by price and filtered to show only the hostels. You have more than 1000 options to choose from 7 euros.

This is just an example and have in mind that Booking has not all hostels in Japan, but probably most of them.

Note that if you just want the list of cities with hostels, you can refer to the list that appears in the left sidebar once you filter by "hostel" (26 cities in the example).

Comment: I am actually amazed!

Comment: I've had luck with a similar approach finding a cheap hostel with Booking's map feature and filtering by price.